# What color should Cb and Cr channels have for the pixel in RGB to be red?

Tags: php, image, rgb

If I converted an image from `RGB` to `YCbCr` what values should I give to Cb and Cr thus converted back to `RGB` for the pixel to be red?

Comment: Convert an RGB red pixel to YCbCr in your environment and see what you get.

Comment: The figure in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr could help you to understand the CbCr values